# Regarding the etiquette of removing "Accepted" but downvoted Answers

Tags: discussion

This is regarding this specific discourse:

[How do I get newest version of adobe flashplayer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848885/how-do-i-get-newest-version-of-adobe-flashplayer/848903#848903)

Before I ask, I should point out that I understand that not everyone will agree with every answer, and that downvoting is part of the process here.  I accept that my post may get downvoted, regardless of if it is correct or not.  **This is not a complaint**, but more of a question about etiquette.

My question is this:

*If I have provided an Answer and the OP has accepted it (even going so far as to comment that it worked), but the answer is being downvoted, what do I do?*

As a member who has relatively low rep, I would normally just remove the answer I provided, especially if there is already another answer that explains it better than I can.

My question is something I can find no rules for, and I'd like to know what I should do in this situation.

Do I leave it, and risk losing more rep? (detrimental for a low rep user like myself)

Or

Do I remove it, knowing full well it is the answer that fixed the problem?

I'll continue to edit it in the mean time.  Hopefully I can reverse the votes :)

Comment: I don't know if you can remove your answer if it's been accepted.

Comment: You should also ping the user (@username) so the know you've made an edit.

Comment: Ouch.  That seems counter productive.  If the answer cannot be removed, shouldn't voting on it also be disabled after it's been accepted?

Comment: No, because that would be stupid. Voting is there so that people can voice their opinion on something. We aren't going to take that away. There are cases when OP will just accept the first answer posted, just because it was posted.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the system is open to abuse?  I mean, for a low rep user, if there was enough disagreement, you could have one answer literally destroy all of your reputation.

Comment: This is true, but the situation you describe is not abuse. If your answer is so bad that it gets enough downvotes for you to lose 454 rep (that'd be 227 downvotes), then there are ways to delete it.

Comment: As for actual voting abuse, if someone is serial voting all your posts (whether up or down) there is a system in place that will detect these votes and reverse them.

Comment: Oh, I get that.  But my question is related to this specific instance in the linked question.  I mean, you can see it's not a bad answer, and the OP even stated it fixed the issue.  If it were a poor answer, then I would understand the downvote, and edit/remove accordingly.  But it isn't.  Is it?

Comment: I was respoding to your abuse speculation.

Comment: I understand.  At least it kind of answers some of my question, thanks.

Comment: It is worth noting, an accept is worth 15 rep and a downvote is -2, so by removing your answer, you would loose 13 rep.

Comment: Thanks.  I think my primary concern was the potential for abuse.

Comment: Seems to me rep was your concern, you did not even mention abuse in the question "Do I leave it, and risk losing more rep?" but that is my point anyway, it can't be abused, it would take 8 downvotes to cancel out the accept and only the very worst post get anything like that many votes.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're reading this as something I'd take personally. Honestly, stepping away from AU would not be an issue to me, nor would the community feel the loss. I'm not a huge asset to have around, and sometimes my opinions overtake my desire for pure reason. That said, I'd like to improve, that's why I'm here. Not for any other real reason. I posted this originally to start the discussion. No one else had, and thought it was something that should be talked about. This has no real emotional significance. Just a topic I thought might be worthy. :)

Comment: I am not saying wanting to keep rep is a bad thing, we all want to keep our rep of course. I am simply trying to reassure you that one vote is no big deal. "Honestly, stepping away from AU would not be an issue to me, nor would the community feel the loss. I'm not a huge asset to have around, and sometimes my opinions overtake my desire for pure reason." Every user is an asset, no matter there rep, your question is very valid and exactly what meta is for. It takes time to get good here, you are doing well, please keep it up.

Comment: LOL!  I edited the question, and immediately got another downvote.

Comment: @ThatGuy Looking at the edits you made, the amount of surplus info is out of control, you should of deleted the old stuff and just kept the new `correct` part, that is why I would guess you got another downvote.

Comment: Its ok.  I gave up in the end.  The OP removed the answer, and I thought "Stuff it" and just deleted the post altogether.  There's no pleasing some people.  The OP said it was fine to begin with, then someone complained I didn't do it right, then someone complained I wasn't explaining.  You cant please all the people all the time, right?  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your question of what to do in this case is **don't worry about it and do nothing with the answer - focus on writing more good questions and answers.**

You answered the question and it was accepted by the OP.  Great, that means you solved the problem, and got some rep from that!  But, your answer got a downvote.  It would be great to find out why!  It looks like it may have been because your suggested course of action is unclear.  In which case, you should clarify it.  A lot of times, reading the comments is a useful thing - it helps give you guidance towards what may be wrong.  Sometimes there are no comments; it never hurts to ask people "Hey, I'm getting downvoted, can someone perhaps explain to me what's wrong" in your own comment on your answer.

Your answer is pretty good, though the specifics about what you are proposing may appear unclear for users, and you may need to clarify more specifically why you're proposing the answer you did.  (Even though it's accepted by the OP and solved their issue)

In this single case, though, you've only got a single downvote.  Don't fret, we all get our posts downvoted at some point or another!

---

My advice, in detail:

1. ***Do not remove your answer, which actually helped the OP.***  This is the first thing you need to care about - did your answer actually help the OP, and if it did and they accepted it, it's unlikely you'll want to delete it, in case it helps others with the same problem.  Even if the system permitted you to do this, you should do a lot of thinking before deleting posts - it's not the best solution to things.

   Also, don't delete things that aren't absolute junk - your answer doesn't qualify as junk, so unless it's flat out wrong you should leave it be.
2. ***Don't worry about downvotes and reputation points so much***.  Regardless of your reputation level.

   Reputation points are only there for the purposes of showing contribution and gaining privileges the more you contribute positively.  If you continue to post good questions and answers, you won't need to worry about losing a small number of points from a downvote.

   What you should worry about is when you start getting a bunch of downvotes on a specific question or answer (but not getting all your posts downvoted in a suspicious way).  If you start getting these, and it's not because of serial downvoting, then it's possibly a problem with your answer - whether quality of the answer or accuracy of the answer, or whatever.  That's when you should re-evaluate your answer - see if you can make it more clear, or update it if the solution is outdated.

   A side note on worrying about downvotes though - if your posts get serially downvoted by a voting ring in an abusive format (and I mean beyond that which you could expect from an unclear or wrong answer), contact a moderator to look into whether this is a serial downvoting situation.  The system (and us moderators) have tools and procedures for handling these cases, and one of the things we're here to do is make sure these things aren't happening, because we don't like people abusing the systems.
3. ***Just keep posting good questions and answers!***  This is the best thing you can do - one or two downvotes are not something I would worry about, because posting more good questions and answers will get you reputation to offset a couple of downvotes.  Reputation is also not necessarily the driving force for posting on Ask Ubuntu - your primary drive should be to help others, and to ask good questions and provide good answers, not worrying about every single point of rep you have.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes much more sense.  I've had two reasons for being concerned over rep.  Firstly, according to the documentation I've read about how to ask/answer and award/receive rep, it said that it was a "measure of trust" and of "quality".  This to me is the most important, and made me worry that it would harm or hinder that trust.  Secondly, I was concerned about the possible abuse.  But given there is a process whereby this can be addressed, I'm happy with this answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ThatGuy "Measure of trust" goes to privilege levels.  "Quality" is more or less inaccurate - it's just a measure of your existing posts' quality. Neither are a great indicator of quality much.  The core thing is not worrying about reputation as much and instead worry about your contributions.   When the majority of your posts are of good quality, you have nothing to worry about.  And you've only been here a month - don't fret as much over one or two downvotes, we all get them, and the good people will comment as to why the downvote happened and suggest how to improve :)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the explanation. Very helpful :)

Comment: @ThatGuy You're welcome!  I hope you continue to enjoy your time here on Ask Ubuntu :)